# Difference between node and nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Will it make changes if I start a file by running `nodemon index.js` and not `node index.js`?

> In Node.js, you need to restart the process to make changes take effect. This adds an extra step to your workflow to have the changes take place. You can eliminate this extra step by using nodemon to restart the process automatically.

Node needs to restart but makes changes take effect, and nodemon restarts the proccess automatically.

I dont get this part, can someone explain this to me? Does it mean nodemon restarts the proccess without crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node is the standard command to use in node.js to run any javascript in the console. when you run node index.js it will serve your app and thats it. when you use nodemon index.js it  will serve your app and listen for changes to the document/project and recompile, updating the output of localhost

Comment: There isn't standard commands to run javascript (others can exist). Node is a javascript runtime, which means it'll execute a javascript code, serving or not (you can run a simple Hello World using node without serving it). Nodemon is a tool that listen for changes in files and then restart a node application. In both cases, it could be a server application or not. It does not matter.

Comment: I understand. I did state that the node command will run ANY JavaScript in the console. Meaning that you could write node 1 + 2 and it will spit out 3. I gave an answer based off how I believe the person who asked it is trying to using it. You are just playing semantics at this point.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch your node.js application with Nodemon it will monitor for any changes and automatically restart the server, improving your productivity.

Nodemon is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server.

for example - I use nodemon when editing and developing on local server. instead of canceling and restarting a server every-time you want to see the changes you have made, nodemon will automatically restart when you save your code. I use atom, so, as soon as I hit "ctr + s" in atom to save, it will automatically restart the server.  once I refresh the webpage the changes will be there. I have run into a few instances where I have had to restart my nodemon for changes to take effect, this usually only happens if I have added a lot with out saving in-between and multiple changes need to be applied.

Comment: I have a json like this:
```
..
"scripts:" {
"dev": "nodemon index.js",
"start": "node index.js"
}
```

Is this how you use nodemon? is it gonna automatically run nodemon index.js if I do node index.js?

Comment: If that is in your package.json and if you type in the console "npm run dev" or "npm run start" to launch your app then yes